# Does any major language have an "or if" / "also if" conditional, and if not, why not?

Tags: programming-languages, conditional-statements

A friend of mine was learning to program and he asked me why there isn't an "`and if`" / "`also if`" / "`or if`" statement (non-exclusive or), where multiple, independent test conditions with independent results can be met that would prevent any "`else`" conditions from triggering. **Edit**: I think my choice of "or" may have been a bad keyword here, because the `or` keyword is usually evaluated lazily, so the second branch never fires. What I'm talking about is something where *all* the true conditions fire, but if there are *no* true conditions among the `or if`s, then you move on to the `else`/`elif` branch.

Here is an example (using python syntax):

```py
if a:
    print('a evaluates True')
orif b:
    print('b evaluates True')
else:
    print('Both a and b evaluate False')
```

The way this is different from `elif` is that in the event that **both** `a` and `b` are true, the output of this would be:

```py
a evaluates True
b evaluates True
```

Whereas in an `elif`, the output of that conditional would be:

```py
a evaluates True
```

I got on my "I've been programming for years" hat and started to explain, "Well, of course there's no `orif` statement because...", but I couldn't come up with a good reason. A good example of this concept is [fizzbuzz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizzbuzz), where you are asked to print all numbers between 1 and 100, but with all numbers divisible by 3 replaced by `fizz`, all numbers divisible by 5 replaced by `buzz` and all numbers divisible by both 3 and 5 replaced by `fizzbuzz`.  Using an "`orif`" syntax, it can be accomplished with a single conditional:

```py
for x in range(1, 100):
    outstr = ""
    if x%3 == 0:
        outstr += "fizz"
    orif x%5 == 0:
        outstr += "buzz"
    else:
        outstr = x

    print(x)
```

But without it, you're stuck with something less elegant, either switching to three conditionals and at least one additional modulo evaluation:

```py
for x in range(0, 100):
    outstr = ""
    if x%3 == 0:
        outstr += "fizz"

    if x%5 == 0:
        outstr += "buzz"

    if not x%15 == 0:       # Could also be not (x%3 and x%5)
        outstr = x

    print(x)
```

Or you can avoid the extra modulo operation by storing them ahead of time:

```py
for x in range(0, 100):
    outstr = ""
    fizz = (x%3 == 0)
    buzz = (x%5 == 0)

    if fizz:
        outstr += "fizz"

    if buzz:
        outstr += "buzz"

    if not (fizz or buzz):
        outstr = x

    print(x)
```

There are obviously other ways to accomplish this, but none of them are quite as intuitive as the "orif" structure. Looking back, I've noticed that this is something I've actually come up against *many* times, where I have a number of conditions with different effects that each need to be evaluated, and a default condition that occurs if *none* of them are met. I usually "solve" this problem by having an annoying "flag" variable in each of the separate conditionals:

```py
OneConditionMet = False
if a:
    # Do the "a" stuff
    OneConditionMet = True

if b:
    # Do the "b" stuff
    OneConditionMet = True

#       ...

if n:
    # Do the "n" stuff
    OneConditionMet = True

if not OneConditionMet:
    # Do the default behavior.
```

Obviously this is a quite inelegant and annoying way to do this, another problem solved by "orif". So, given all these clear reasons for an "`orif`", I was shocked to find in the [Wikipedia article on conditionals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If-then-else#Else_if) that there isn't *any* mention of anything similar. This makes me think that there's something fundamental I'm missing about why this doesn't work. The only reason I can think of is the fact that as constructed above, the evaluation would need to be slightly less lazy because it would need to check if any "or if" branches occur even if the first "if" condition were met. That's a pretty easy problem to solve, though, because you could just make it so that if you have any `or if` statements in the conditional tree, then *all* `if` statements need to be `or if` statements, like such:

```py
orif a:
    print('a evaluates True')
orif b:
    print('b evaluates True')
else:
    print('Neither a nor b evaluate True')
```

So, there's the question - am I missing something that's fundamentally equivalent to this? Am I missing some reason why it's fundamentally unworkable, or is this just a huge missed opportunity?

Comment: python has `if`, `elif`, `else` construct.  Many other languages have `switch`, `case`, `default` statements

Comment: None of those constructs actually do what this does. In C the `switch` construct comes closest because multiple branches can execute, but it can't go down the line and evaluate multiple conditions like that.

Comment: So you want condition `a` and `b` to execute independently of each other and have a `else` across both?  I can think of very few times when something like this would be useful without already having some variable set I could key off of.

Comment: @cmd Well it's actually come up for me multiple times, including as you'll notice in fizzbuzz, which is a sort of iconic "beginner's problem" in programming, which is one reason I'm surprised that there seems to be no mention of anyone trying it.

Comment: `fizzbuzz` has a variable already existing to key off. `outstr`

Comment: Sure, but that's once again an inelegant solution to the problem, involving an additional unnecessary conditional evaluation. This obviously adds no core functionality to any Turing-complete programming language, it's just surprising to me that there seem to be *no* examples of this thing occurring when it feels like the natural way to do things.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding how this `orif` is different from the `else if` construct that most languages allow. Can you give an example of something that would be better written using `orif` than `else if`?

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify, I had thought that the fizzbuzz example was clearer than it appears to have been to many people. The difference is that ALL `orif` conditions would fire, not just the first one that matches, and the `else` conditions only fire when NO `orif` conditions match.

Comment: In python 3.10 switch statements are available!!

Answer (score 1):

What you asking for is alternatively described as pattern-matching or decision table. Even so, getting the right behaviour on the false branch is not easy, and I've not seen any languages that do exactly that.

Pattern matching languages (like awk) fire every rule that matches a pattern. You need some extra code to record whether any rule fired and fire the else rule if not.

Decision table software was popular (as a preprocessor) at least 30 years ago. Essentially you put what the tests and actions are into a table, and the system analyses what's left over so as to execute a default action.

Personally, I don't think it's that useful. There are real problems in managing complex sets of if tests, and I don't think this single feature would resolve many of them. In a lot of these cases you can naturally ensure that the else case is detected because some variable never got touched. There are harder combinations that take serious planning to avoid utter confusion.

BTW the use of 'andif' and 'orif' are unhelpful. They really do make one think of something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not aware of any. but...

first of all be aware that your 'parallel if' is almost exact equivalent to sequence of standard 'if'. the only difference is just the `else` clause. and if predicate computation is expensive you can always cache it (like in your example with modulo)

when we are talking about imperative/OOP everyone tries to use inheritance and some functional idioms (like all kinds of 'optional') simply to remove branching. it's being said that the only `switch/case` statements are allowed inside factories and they should have no logic and do absolutely nothing except returning some kind of enum.

when we are talking about functional programming then it seems this construct is even less useful. functional programs tends be function compositions. each expressions should return a single value and has (almost) none side effects. so this construct would discard return values from almost all branches and would be useful only for non-pure code which should be isolated.

when i try to recall my code from my everyday work i can't really find a place where i would want to use it. so maybe it's simply not needed in general purpose languages. but you can always implement as a macro

Answer (score -1):

I think that `orif` construct is not a good fit in C because it would be too complicated. All existing C statements have simple syntax and have only one sub-statement. For instance in `for` you have

```
for (clause; expression; expression)
    statement
```

Even switch, which is the most complicated one, uses one sub-statement and a trick of using `case` as labels similar to `goto` labels. The `orif` would be very different - it would need an arbitrary number of sub-statements and their corresponding conditions.

From this perspective, `orif` would be a beast of completely different kind than all existing C statements. Today, though many popular languages provide various constructs not found in C, the fundamental statements like loops and conditionals are in many cases inherited from C (with changes obviously but still). And the arguments I presented for C apply to many other languages too. (Not all, since e.g. Python has similar `elif`.) I guess that at least partially explains why there is no `orif`.